VS Code src/main/resources not included in the class path
Using VS Code I am trying to access the file application.conf located in the resources folder of a java maven project:

In the projects setting I have src/main/resources in the classpath:

Unfortunately running maven lifecyles the resources folder is not available in the target/classes folder:

Hence the java program with VS Code cannot access any file in the resources folder, how can I add src/main/resources to the class path? (right click folder -> add "Add Folder to Java Source Path" does not work with maven in VS Code)

Don't you want the Output be target/classes/resources?

This question is similar to: Resources and config loading in maven project. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
